# Flutter, IOS, how to make Native admob UI

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm familiar with Android and Flutter, but I don't know anything about IOS.

I decided to ask here because I need the IOS code only once.

I`m currently following this by referring to https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads and https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#7.

I'm doing it in Swift.

First, I copied the UI code of Native Advanced Example from https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/releases/tag/7.22.

ListTileNativeAdView.xib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14113" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment version="2048" identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB" customClass="GADUnifiedNativeAdView">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iNa-bH-h1m">
                    <rect key="frame" x="15" y="16" width="40" height="40"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="ICz-3W-FQf"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="40" id="vY6-8D-xIn"/>
                    </constraints>
                </imageView>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Advertiser" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GTT-Yh-eSq">
                    <rect key="frame" x="63" y="39" width="66.5" height="17"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" placeholderIntrinsicWidth="100" placeholderIntrinsicHeight="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2Of-AP-0h9">
                    <rect key="frame" x="129.5" y="38.5" width="100" height="17"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="17" id="jBW-Cz-Kyc"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="100" id="sXk-zk-NI0"/>
                    </constraints>
                </imageView>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" verticalCompressionResistancePriority="751" text="Body that is really really long and can take up to two lines or sometimes even more." textAlignment="justified" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PEQ-D9-2Vv">
                    <rect key="frame" x="15" y="63.5" width="350" height="33.5"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <button opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="E5w-YA-UY8">
                    <rect key="frame" x="317" y="259.5" width="48" height="34"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Install">
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" red="0.5" green="0.5" blue="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </state>
                </button>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Price" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ysb-of-cat">
                    <rect key="frame" x="229" y="267.5" width="33" height="17"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Store" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hwF-UL-Q8H">
                    <rect key="frame" x="272" y="268" width="35" height="17"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="751" text="Headline" textAlignment="justified" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="beR-eV-DX1">
                    <rect key="frame" x="63" y="10" width="297" height="20.5"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="20.5" id="6r8-Hu-d0y"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <view contentMode="scaleAspectFit" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fNp-yu-K4i" customClass="GADMediaView">
                    <rect key="frame" x="62" y="102" width="250" height="150"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" priority="999" constant="150" id="JYO-VS-mga"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="250" id="e3T-fD-di4"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Ad" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="lp1-oz-XOs">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="15" height="15"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.80000001190000003" blue="0.40000000600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="15" id="Twa-Vk-uWQ"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="15" id="k8m-kJ-CF5"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" weight="semibold" pointSize="11"/>
                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.98303861469999998" blue="0.92887652860000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="GTT-Yh-eSq" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="beR-eV-DX1" secondAttribute="leading" id="0sB-Mk-EU6"/>
                <constraint firstItem="lp1-oz-XOs" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" id="3lA-qv-Nkc"/>
                <constraint firstItem="Ysb-of-cat" firstAttribute="leading" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="3pc-w6-uy1"/>
                <constraint firstItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" firstAttribute="top" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="iNa-bH-h1m" secondAttribute="bottom" id="4S3-p0-z6A"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="8U0-Fb-3R7"/>
                <constraint firstItem="iNa-bH-h1m" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" constant="15" id="9WK-zC-xET"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="beR-eV-DX1" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="15" id="BcE-do-dNl"/>
                <constraint firstItem="lp1-oz-XOs" firstAttribute="left" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="left" id="BpX-yC-PZG"/>
                <constraint firstItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2Of-AP-0h9" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="CCg-xe-cKg"/>
                <constraint firstItem="2Of-AP-0h9" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="beR-eV-DX1" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="ESC-Pe-TXR"/>
                <constraint firstItem="iNa-bH-h1m" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="2Of-AP-0h9" secondAttribute="bottom" id="GwM-y0-1du"/>
                <constraint firstItem="beR-eV-DX1" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iNa-bH-h1m" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="MRN-dd-Oip"/>
                <constraint firstItem="2Of-AP-0h9" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="GTT-Yh-eSq" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Med-Nd-wEo"/>
                <constraint firstItem="beR-eV-DX1" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="Mvs-eV-Wzb"/>
                <constraint firstItem="Ysb-of-cat" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="hwF-UL-Q8H" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Rud-i8-Myz"/>
                <constraint firstItem="fNp-yu-K4i" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="centerX" id="TYN-lq-3DK"/>
                <constraint firstItem="fNp-yu-K4i" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="V0m-hf-6NS"/>
                <constraint firstItem="GTT-Yh-eSq" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="2Of-AP-0h9" secondAttribute="centerY" id="YgR-kp-age"/>
                <constraint firstItem="hwF-UL-Q8H" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Ysb-of-cat" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="aLb-sm-wAb"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="right" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="lp1-oz-XOs" secondAttribute="right" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="czi-qD-IaJ"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="E5w-YA-UY8" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="eNM-dN-tvx"/>
                <constraint firstItem="E5w-YA-UY8" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hwF-UL-Q8H" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="f39-vH-KWq"/>
                <constraint firstItem="Ysb-of-cat" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="fNp-yu-K4i" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="15.5" id="fP8-wI-mHH"/>
                <constraint firstItem="iNa-bH-h1m" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" secondAttribute="leading" id="mof-5F-8vM"/>
                <constraint firstItem="E5w-YA-UY8" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="hwF-UL-Q8H" secondAttribute="centerY" id="rNj-VY-YrO"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="E5w-YA-UY8" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="uEI-XT-igi"/>
            </constraints>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="advertiserView" destination="GTT-Yh-eSq" id="bY8-5O-6fF"/>
                <outlet property="bodyView" destination="PEQ-D9-2Vv" id="Gpd-Q6-Byv"/>
                <outlet property="callToActionView" destination="E5w-YA-UY8" id="RCf-yK-s1x"/>
                <outlet property="headlineView" destination="beR-eV-DX1" id="d1E-ed-yel"/>
                <outlet property="iconView" destination="iNa-bH-h1m" id="gIe-xy-iwm"/>
                <outlet property="mediaView" destination="fNp-yu-K4i" id="624-ZP-L04"/>
                <outlet property="priceView" destination="Ysb-of-cat" id="L6Q-hd-uaJ"/>
                <outlet property="starRatingView" destination="2Of-AP-0h9" id="zCO-9D-S0V"/>
                <outlet property="storeView" destination="hwF-UL-Q8H" id="hRl-23-ce1"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="9.5" y="-8.5"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

ListTileNativeAdFactory.swift

```
// TODO: Import google_mobile_ads
import google_mobile_ads

// TODO: Implement ListTileNativeAdFactory
class ListTileNativeAdFactory : FLTNativeAdFactory {

    func createNativeAd(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd,
                        customOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil) -> GADNativeAdView? {
        let nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ListTileNativeAdView", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first
        let nativeAdView = nibView as! GADNativeAdView

        (nativeAdView.headlineView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.headline

        (nativeAdView.bodyView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.body
        nativeAdView.bodyView!.isHidden = nativeAd.body == nil

        (nativeAdView.iconView as! UIImageView).image = nativeAd.icon?.image
        nativeAdView.iconView!.isHidden = nativeAd.icon == nil

        nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        nativeAdView.nativeAd = nativeAd

        return nativeAdView
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

// TODO: Import google_mobile_ads
import google_mobile_ads

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    // TODO: Register ListTileNativeAdFactory
    let listTileFactory = ListTileNativeAdFactory()
    FLTGoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(
        self, factoryId: "listTile", nativeAdFactory: listTileFactory)

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

and I got this errors

```
ListTileNativeAdFactory.swift:15:71: error: cannot find type 'GADNativeAdView' in scope
                            customOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil) -> GADNativeAdView? {
                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ListTileNativeAdFactory.swift:17:40: error: cannot find type 'GADNativeAdView' in scope
            let nativeAdView = nibView as! GADNativeAdView
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Flutter code is perfect. It works perfectly in Android flutter. The ad unit was also changed for IOS.

I would super appreciate for answers thanks

Comment: It's not your code, it's your project setup or `import` for ad mobs. First of all based on https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start, you need to add the import: `import GoogleMobileAds`. When you add that import, the problem may go away, or it may start giving you error on that import. Which means your project setup is not right (missing Mobile Ads SDK)

Comment: @Kirill S.  Actually, I have a ios admob banner too here and it works well

Comment: @rounpaleum did you solve your problem? Could you answer my question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970468/swift-equivalent-of-objective-c-for-flutter-native-ads

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, after 3 days, I finally found a way to resolve this problem, you need to add some missed lines refer to `ListTileNativeAdFactory.swift`, `ListTileNativeAdView.xib` and `GADNativeAd.h` in `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

Answer (score 0):

This additional changes works for me:)

import google_mobile_ads

import UIKit

class SingisticNativeAdFactory : FLTNativeAdFactory {

```
func createNativeAd(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd,
                    customOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil) -> GADNativeAdView? {
    let nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NativeAdView", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first
    
    
    let nativeAdView = nibView as! GADNativeAdView

    (nativeAdView.headlineView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.headline
    nativeAdView.headlineView!.isHidden = nativeAd.headline == nil


    (nativeAdView.bodyView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.body
    nativeAdView.bodyView!.isHidden = nativeAd.body == nil
    
    (nativeAdView.callToActionView as! UIButton).setTitle(nativeAd.callToAction, for: .normal)
    nativeAdView.callToActionView!.isHidden = nativeAd.callToAction == nil

    (nativeAdView.iconView as! UIImageView).image = nativeAd.icon?.image
    nativeAdView.iconView!.isHidden = nativeAd.icon == nil
    
    (nativeAdView.storeView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.store
    nativeAdView.storeView!.isHidden = nativeAd.store == nil
    
    (nativeAdView.priceView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.price
    nativeAdView.priceView!.isHidden = nativeAd.price == nil
    
    (nativeAdView.advertiserView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.advertiser
    nativeAdView.advertiserView!.isHidden = nativeAd.advertiser == nil
    
    nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    nativeAdView.nativeAd = nativeAd

    return nativeAdView
}
```

}