# Swift Equivalent of Objective-C for Flutter Native Ads

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, admob, native-ads

I want to implement Native Ads for my Flutter project(**It's using Swift, not Objective-C**)

https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/native

Interestingly there is no native ads documentation for swift in flutter. It's only for Objective-c. What is the swift equivalent of these?

Appdelegate:

```
#import "FLTGoogleMobileAdsPlugin.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];

  NativeAdFactoryExample *nativeAdFactory = [[NativeAdFactoryExample alloc] init];
  [FLTGoogleMobileAdsPlugin registerNativeAdFactory:self
                                          factoryId:@"adFactoryExample"
                                    nativeAdFactory:nativeAdFactory];

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

NativeAdFactoryExample:

```
/**
 * The example NativeAdView.xib can be found at
 * //github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/blob/master/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/ios/Runner/NativeAdView.xib
 */
@interface NativeAdFactoryExample : NSObject <FLTNativeAdFactory>
@end

@implementation NativeAdFactoryExample
- (GADNativeAdView *)createNativeAd:(GADNativeAd *)nativeAd
                             customOptions:(NSDictionary *)customOptions {
  // Create and place ad in view hierarchy.
  GADNativeAdView *adView =
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NativeAdView" owner:nil options:nil].firstObject;

  // Associate the native ad view with the native ad object. This is
  // required to make the ad clickable.
  adView.nativeAd = nativeAd;

  // Populate the native ad view with the native ad assets.
  // The headline is guaranteed to be present in every native ad.
  ((UILabel *)adView.headlineView).text = nativeAd.headline;

  // These assets are not guaranteed to be present. Check that they are before
  // showing or hiding them.
  ((UILabel *)adView.bodyView).text = nativeAd.body;
  adView.bodyView.hidden = nativeAd.body ? NO : YES;

  [((UIButton *)adView.callToActionView) setTitle:nativeAd.callToAction
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  adView.callToActionView.hidden = nativeAd.callToAction ? NO : YES;

  ((UIImageView *)adView.iconView).image = nativeAd.icon.image;
  adView.iconView.hidden = nativeAd.icon ? NO : YES;

  ((UILabel *)adView.storeView).text = nativeAd.store;
  adView.storeView.hidden = nativeAd.store ? NO : YES;

  ((UILabel *)adView.priceView).text = nativeAd.price;
  adView.priceView.hidden = nativeAd.price ? NO : YES;

  ((UILabel *)adView.advertiserView).text = nativeAd.advertiser;
  adView.advertiserView.hidden = nativeAd.advertiser ? NO : YES;

  // In order for the SDK to process touch events properly, user interaction
  // should be disabled.
  adView.callToActionView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

  return adView;
}
@end
```

Besides,

How should the **ListTileNativeAdView.xib** file be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#7

You can look this section: **Implement NativeAdFactory for iOS (Swift)**

**ListTileNativeAdFactory.swift:**

```
// TODO: Import google_mobile_ads
import google_mobile_ads

// TODO: Implement ListTileNativeAdFactory
class ListTileNativeAdFactory : FLTNativeAdFactory {

    func createNativeAd(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd,
                        customOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil) -> GADNativeAdView? {
        let nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ListTileNativeAdView", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first
        let nativeAdView = nibView as! GADNativeAdView

        (nativeAdView.headlineView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.headline

        (nativeAdView.bodyView as! UILabel).text = nativeAd.body
        nativeAdView.bodyView!.isHidden = nativeAd.body == nil

        (nativeAdView.iconView as! UIImageView).image = nativeAd.icon?.image
        nativeAdView.iconView!.isHidden = nativeAd.icon == nil

        nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        nativeAdView.nativeAd = nativeAd

        return nativeAdView
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

// TODO: Import google_mobile_ads
import google_mobile_ads

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    // TODO: Register ListTileNativeAdFactory
    let listTileFactory = ListTileNativeAdFactory()
    FLTGoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(
        self, factoryId: "listTile", nativeAdFactory: listTileFactory)

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

For flutter implementation you can look further in this link.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#7

Besides,

You can use xib file at official github

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/blob/main/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/ios/Runner/NativeAdView.xib

**ListTileNativeAdView.xib:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17156" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment version="2048" identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17125"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB" customClass="GADNativeAdView">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iNa-bH-h1m">
                    <rect key="frame" x="15" y="15.5" width="40" height="40"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="ICz-3W-FQf"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="40" id="vY6-8D-xIn"/>
                    </constraints>
                </imageView>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Advertiser" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GTT-Yh-eSq">
                    <rect key="frame" x="63" y="38.5" width="66.5" height="17"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" systemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" placeholderIntrinsicWidth="100" placeholderIntrinsicHeight="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2Of-AP-0h9">
                    <rect key="frame" x="129.5" y="38.5" width="100" height="17"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="17" id="jBW-Cz-Kyc"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="100" id="sXk-zk-NI0"/>
                    </constraints>
                </imageView>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" verticalCompressionResistancePriority="751" text="Body that is really really long and can take up to two lines or sometimes even more." textAlignment="justified" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PEQ-D9-2Vv">
                    <rect key="frame" x="15" y="63.5" width="350" height="33.5"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" systemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="E5w-YA-UY8">
                    <rect key="frame" x="318" y="259.5" width="47" height="34"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Install">
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" red="0.5" green="0.5" blue="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </state>
                </button>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Price" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ysb-of-cat">
                    <rect key="frame" x="230" y="268" width="33" height="17"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" systemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Store" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hwF-UL-Q8H">
                    <rect key="frame" x="273" y="268" width="35" height="17"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" systemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="751" text="Headline" textAlignment="justified" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="beR-eV-DX1">
                    <rect key="frame" x="63" y="10" width="297" height="20.5"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="20.5" id="6r8-Hu-d0y"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" systemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <view contentMode="scaleAspectFit" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fNp-yu-K4i" customClass="GADMediaView">
                    <rect key="frame" x="62.5" y="102" width="250" height="150"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" priority="750" constant="150" id="71m-kn-7Ug"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="250" id="e3T-fD-di4"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Ad" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="lp1-oz-XOs">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="15" height="15"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.80000001190000003" blue="0.40000000600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="15" id="Twa-Vk-uWQ"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="15" id="k8m-kJ-CF5"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" weight="semibold" pointSize="11"/>
                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.98303861469999998" blue="0.92887652860000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="GTT-Yh-eSq" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="beR-eV-DX1" secondAttribute="leading" id="0sB-Mk-EU6"/>
                <constraint firstItem="lp1-oz-XOs" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" id="3lA-qv-Nkc"/>
                <constraint firstItem="Ysb-of-cat" firstAttribute="leading" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="3pc-w6-uy1"/>
                <constraint firstItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" firstAttribute="top" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="iNa-bH-h1m" secondAttribute="bottom" id="4S3-p0-z6A"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="8U0-Fb-3R7"/>
                <constraint firstItem="iNa-bH-h1m" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" constant="15" id="9WK-zC-xET"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="beR-eV-DX1" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="15" id="BcE-do-dNl"/>
                <constraint firstItem="lp1-oz-XOs" firstAttribute="left" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="left" id="BpX-yC-PZG"/>
                <constraint firstItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2Of-AP-0h9" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="CCg-xe-cKg"/>
                <constraint firstItem="2Of-AP-0h9" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="beR-eV-DX1" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="ESC-Pe-TXR"/>
                <constraint firstItem="iNa-bH-h1m" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="2Of-AP-0h9" secondAttribute="bottom" id="GwM-y0-1du"/>
                <constraint firstItem="beR-eV-DX1" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iNa-bH-h1m" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="MRN-dd-Oip"/>
                <constraint firstItem="2Of-AP-0h9" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="GTT-Yh-eSq" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Med-Nd-wEo"/>
                <constraint firstItem="beR-eV-DX1" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="Mvs-eV-Wzb"/>
                <constraint firstItem="Ysb-of-cat" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="hwF-UL-Q8H" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Rud-i8-Myz"/>
                <constraint firstItem="fNp-yu-K4i" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="centerX" id="TYN-lq-3DK"/>
                <constraint firstItem="fNp-yu-K4i" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="V0m-hf-6NS"/>
                <constraint firstItem="GTT-Yh-eSq" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="2Of-AP-0h9" secondAttribute="centerY" id="YgR-kp-age"/>
                <constraint firstItem="hwF-UL-Q8H" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Ysb-of-cat" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="aLb-sm-wAb"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="right" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="lp1-oz-XOs" secondAttribute="right" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="czi-qD-IaJ"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="E5w-YA-UY8" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="eNM-dN-tvx"/>
                <constraint firstItem="E5w-YA-UY8" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hwF-UL-Q8H" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="f39-vH-KWq"/>
                <constraint firstItem="iNa-bH-h1m" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="PEQ-D9-2Vv" secondAttribute="leading" id="mof-5F-8vM"/>
                <constraint firstItem="E5w-YA-UY8" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="hwF-UL-Q8H" secondAttribute="centerY" id="rNj-VY-YrO"/>
                <constraint firstItem="E5w-YA-UY8" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="fNp-yu-K4i" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="7.5" id="rup-e7-1CR"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="E5w-YA-UY8" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="uEI-XT-igi"/>
            </constraints>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="advertiserView" destination="GTT-Yh-eSq" id="bY8-5O-6fF"/>
                <outlet property="bodyView" destination="PEQ-D9-2Vv" id="Gpd-Q6-Byv"/>
                <outlet property="callToActionView" destination="E5w-YA-UY8" id="RCf-yK-s1x"/>
                <outlet property="headlineView" destination="beR-eV-DX1" id="d1E-ed-yel"/>
                <outlet property="iconView" destination="iNa-bH-h1m" id="gIe-xy-iwm"/>
                <outlet property="mediaView" destination="fNp-yu-K4i" id="624-ZP-L04"/>
                <outlet property="priceView" destination="Ysb-of-cat" id="L6Q-hd-uaJ"/>
                <outlet property="starRatingView" destination="2Of-AP-0h9" id="zCO-9D-S0V"/>
                <outlet property="storeView" destination="hwF-UL-Q8H" id="hRl-23-ce1"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="13.768115942028986" y="-5.6919642857142856"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="darkTextColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="darkTextColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="darkTextColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="darkTextColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="darkTextColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Hey, I am getting `Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find
'ListTileNativeAdFactory' in scope` error. I just followed his tutorial as well. Did you have that error as well?

Comment: Hi, did you implement ListTileNativeAdFactory.swift & register it in AppDelegate? I did not encounter with this problem.

Comment: @chichi open the flutter iOS "Runner" project in Xcode and make sure the file ListTileNativeAdFactory is in the Runner directory where AppDelegate is located. If now right click on that runner directory and "Add files to runner"